# Change the all the keys in a array in php

Tags: php, arrays

So I am playing around with arrays and I want to replace all of the keys in the array, so I have this array:

```
$array = array(1,5,8,0);
```

and this is how I replace the keys:

```
function recursive_change_key($arr, $set) {
if (is_array($arr) && is_array($set)) {
    $newArr = array();
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        $key = array_key_exists( $k, $set) ? $set[$k] : $k;
        $newArr[$key] = is_array($v) ? recursive_change_key($v, $set) : $v;
    }
    return $newArr;
}
return $arr;
}
$length = sizeof($array);
for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
{
  $people = recursive_change_key($array, array($i => "A"));
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($people);
echo '</pre>';
```

So what I am trying to do is to replace all the array keys with A, but this is the result what I get:

[image]

And this is the result what I want:

[image]

(sorry for the bad editing)

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Could you please help?

Comment: You cannot have duplicate keys in an array. Perhaps you want `Array("A" => Array(1, 5, 8, 0))`?

Comment: What's the reason you want all the keys to be the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result you want is not possible to get. There cannot be several entries with the same key. For example, imagine you have general array `$myArray`, is it possible to have 3 `$myArray[0]` ? The answer is no and the same situation is with associative array.

Comment: thank you for your anwser, I will try something else.